# Search in ElasticSearch

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, laravel-5.3

I have a problem in elasticsearch. In the console Kibana, I am executing this code,

```
GET bounce_gmd/_search
{
 "query": { "match_phrase": { "date_added": "2017-02-08" } },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
   "date_added": {
     "terms": {
      "field": "bounce_type.keyword"
      }
     }
   }
 }
```

And I have this result.

```
{
 "took": 1,
 "timed_out": false,
 "_shards": {
 "total": 5,
 "successful": 5,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 129812,
"max_score": 0,
"hits": []
},
 ........................... and many more lines.
```

But when I am running from my laravel project I haven't this result.
My php code is looking like this,

```
$params['index'] = $index_name;
$params['type']  = $index_name;
$params['body']  = $json;
$params['body']['query']['match_phrase']['date_added'] = $now_time;
$params['body']['size']=0;
$params['body']['aggs']['bounce_type']['terms']['field']='bounce_type.keyword';
$response = $client->search($params);
```

Here $index_name='bounce_gmd' and $now_time="2017-02-08".

But the answer is,

[image: Answer]

I change the code to,

```
$json='{
 "query": { "match_phrase": { "date_added": "2017-02-08" } },
  "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
     "date_added": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "bounce_type.keyword"
        }
      }
     }
   }
  ';
$params = [
        'index' =>  $index_name,
        'type' =>  $index_name,
        'body' => $json
    ];
```

But still the answer is same. I didn't understand what is the problem. Please help me.

Comment: can you print the query made by your php code?

Comment: How you want the query in sql form? I try the query from this page. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_search_operations.html

Answer (score 0):

Why do you specify size on 0? It should have some value. And your aggregations can also contain possible size (it should take max possible options for each aggs). Some example of working query:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
   "query" : {
    "match" : { 
        "body": 
        {
        "query":"press key handler ",
        "operator":"or",
        "analyzer":"english"
      }
      }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "category_aggs" : { "terms" : { "field": "category", "size":25}},
    "year_aggs" : { "terms" : { "field": "year", "size":30}},
    "post_type_aggs" : { "terms" : { "field": "post_type", "size":2}}
  }
}
```

Comment: I change the code to `{
  
"query": { "match": { "body" :{ "date_added": "2017-02-08" }} },
"from" : 0,
  "size": 10,
  "aggs": {
    "date_added": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "bounce_type.keyword",
  "size":25
      }
      
    }
  }
}`. But got another error. 'parsing_exception: [match] query does not support [date_added]'

Comment: @Avishake "body" is my example field name, in your case instead of "body" use "date_added"